# Accelerometer, calculate 1 meter

Tags: android

I receive the x axis data from my accelerometer,

```
...
float x = event.values[0];
...
```

how I can calculate 1 meter and popup a toast message?

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 meter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, not from just acceleration.  Remember your basic physics:

x= .5*a*t^2+v_0*t+x_0.

Even if you assume x_0=0 (you just want the change in position), you need to know your initial velocity to determine final position via the accelerometer.

Your other problem is going to be noise.  Accelerometers are just too noisy to use in this manner.

If you want to calculate distance, use GPS.  It still won't work for such short distances, but it will get you closer than an accelerometer.